# Follow up on apex trigger with cross objects

Tags: trigger, field-update

This is a follow up on this morning thread.  And thanks to both person who have helped me this morning. 
Now, I'm trying to get a bit more fency (well the business logic wasn't well developed at the start)

I have an object "shipment__c" with fields, among others, "CIF_Value__c", "Exporter_Account__c", "Shipment_Account__c", "Invoice_Name__c". I have another object called "Account_Move_c" with fields "Amount_c", "From_account__c", "To_Account_c", "Description_c".

I'm trying to automatically create a record on "Account_Move_c" each time the field "CIF_Value__c" of a record on "Shipment_c" is either created or updated. It doesn't seem too complicated to do, but I'm stuck with
1> how to focus on the CIF_Value__c field (only when that one is created or updated with create or change the account move)
2> The account_move should only be created in the case of "is.Insert" otherwise (when is.Update) we should update the already existing account_move.

I believe my problem comes with the updating Account_Move_c when a CIF_Value__c has been changed (because we added more products to a shipment for instance.)

Here is how I've attempted:

```
trigger AccountingMoveLoading2 on Shipment__c (after insert, after update) {

   if (Trigger.isInsert) {
        List<Accounting_Move__c> listaccountingmove = new List<Accounting_Move__c>();

        for (Shipment__c oShipment : trigger.New) {
            Accounting_Move__c oAccounting_Move = new Accounting_Move__c();
            oAccounting_Move.Accounting_Move_Date__c = oShipment.ETD__c;
            oAccounting_Move.Accounting_Move_Description__c = oShipment.Invoice_Name__c;
            oAccounting_Move.From_Account__c = oShipment.Exporter_Account__c;
            oAccounting_Move.To_Account__c = oShipment.Shipment_Account__c;
            oAccounting_Move.Transaction_Amount__c = oShipment.CIF_Value__c;
         listaccountingmove.add(oAccounting_Move);
         }
         insert listaccountingmove;
         }

    else {
        List<Accounting_Move__c> listaccountingmove = new List<Accounting_Move__c>();

        for (Shipment__c oShipment : trigger.New) {
            Accounting_Move__c oAccounting_Move = new Accounting_Move__c();
            oAccounting_Move.Accounting_Move_Date__c = oShipment.ETD__c;
            oAccounting_Move.Accounting_Move_Description__c = oShipment.Invoice_Name__c;
            oAccounting_Move.From_Account__c = oShipment.Exporter_Account__c;
            oAccounting_Move.To_Account__c = oShipment.Shipment_Account__c;
            oAccounting_Move.Transaction_Amount__c = oShipment.CIF_Value__c;
        listaccountingmove.add(oAccounting_Move);
        }
        update listaccountingmove;
        }

}
```

and I naturally get this error.
Error:Apex trigger AccountingMoveLoading2 caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: AccountingMoveLoading2: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []: Trigger.AccountingMoveLoading2: line 31, column 1.

Now, I don't know how to call for the ID on the update conditions.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I put your code in a code formatted block.  When you are entering a question look at the "toolbar" above the text area input for various formatting options, one of which is the code formatting option.  :-)

Comment: Thanks Peter for mentioning the toolbar to me.  I'll make sure to use it next time.  Merry Xmas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is happening because you are using the update statement without specifying an ID on the record.  The update statement requires a record ID to be specified on each record so that the system knows which record should be updated.

You need to set the Id field and use [update](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_update.htm) or a use an external ID and [upsert](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_upsert.htm). Right now, your code is not doing anything to connect the records you are instantiating to any records in the DB.

If you have a Lookup relationship from Shipment__c to Accounting_Move__c then you'll already have access to the ID, so you'd just add another line of code to your for loop to set it.  You may also want to change your [update](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_update.htm) statement to be [upsert](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_upsert.htm) if it is possible that a Shipment__c will not yet have its Accounting_Move__c set at this point.

```
List<Accounting_Move__c> listaccountingmove = new List<Accounting_Move__c>();

for (Shipment__c oShipment : trigger.New) {
    Accounting_Move__c oAccounting_Move = new Accounting_Move__c();
    oAccounting_Move.Id = oShipment.Accounting_Move__c;
    /* set all of your other fields */
    listaccountingmove.add(oAccounting_Move);
 }
 update listaccountingmove; // possibly change to upsert listaccountingmove
```

If you don't have a Lookup relationship, you should probably add one if a Shipment__c can only ever have one Accounting_Move__c which your question describes.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  But I don't want to insert a record several time.  Only once.

Comment: Ah.  OK.  I updated my answer to reflect that you want to update the one and only Accounting_Move__c related to the Shipment__c.